# Why does disabling an HTML button obstruct keyboard eventListener (Firefox only)?

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener, keydown

My webpage has an HTML button that triggers some javascript which users interact with using the keyboard.  The button is hidden and disabled after the first click.  The problem is that after I disable this button, the keyboard eventListener no longer registers keypresses.  The keyboard events start working again after clicking anywhere on the webpage.  This problem occurs on Firefox 89.0.2, but neither on Chrome 91.0.4472.124 nor on Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.67.

The code is set up like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <input type="button" id="startButton" value="Click to do stuff" onclick="stuff()">

</body>
</html>
```

```
function stuff(){
  document.getElementById("startButton").style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide button
  document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = true; //firefox users have to click again after this
  //do stuff
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  //do more stuff with keyboard inputs
});
```

I have tried running the webpage without disabling the button but that causes some other firefox-only bugs (such as spacebar presses inexplicably triggering the button and therefore the `stuff()` function again).  Please share any insights why disabling this button prevents keyboard events being detected (on firefox only) and how to keep the eventListener active without asking users to click the screen again.

Comment: Probably has to do with focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting find and I'd call it a bug on Firefox's side. It's the `disabled` state causing this. In theory, it should still keep bubbling the `keydown` event, just like in Chrome.

To fix this issue, just call `.blur()` on your button to make sure it gives the focus away:

```js
function stuff(){
  const button = document.getElementById("startButton");
  button.style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide button
  button.disabled = true; //firefox users have to click again after this
  button.blur();
  //do stuff
}
```

**Bonus hint**

Instead of setting visibility explicitly, how about setting this CSS rule?

```css
#startButton:disabled {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: "In theory, it should still keep bubbling the keydown event, just like in Chrome" No, that the keydown event is prevented sounds like the correct behavior. The bug is that they should blur the input automatically since disabled inputs should not be focusable. However the fact that the keydown is prevented is a good sign.

Comment: @Kaiido keep in mind that this bug is more serious than just "keeping the focus". It's weird that it literally ignores key presses for a disabled button. If you prevent the button from becoming disabled, it will work just fine, even though the focus is on the button.

Comment: No it is not weird at all, disabled elements should not receive any inputs.

Comment: Should they also prevent the key events from bubbling up? That's where I'm not sure

Comment: Yes, only ShadowDOM is able to change the target of an event, that they mute this event is kind of expected / less worse than bubbling.

Comment: I guess you're right. Technically, disabled elements should be unable to take any focus, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what the specs ask for. But as youmay have seen, my bug report got closed as duplicate of an other one, reported 21 years ago oO. Must not be that big of a breaker, and I wouldn't hold my breath for any change there ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido haha LOL :D

Comment: Thank you @RoboRobok for your answer, which provides an elegant workaround for this issue.  And also thank you for the slick CSS trick as well.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido for your insight as well and for opening the bug on bugzilla.  It is interesting that this is still an issue despite being identified 21 years ago.  Unsurprisingly, firefox 90 still has this undesired behavior :/